# Buffer overflow example

Tags: security, assembly, buffer-overflow

I try to experiment with a buffer overflow exploit for the purposes of coding learning.

I follow an example and I successfully made it to the point, where my *eip* points to the address where I store instructions to be executed. However, *gdb* shows me message:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xffffcf7c in ?? ()`
0xffffcf7c is correct address where my NOP sequence is. But the code is not executed. Any ideas why my code stops there?

Comment: Your system may be set up to run programs with a non-executable stack.  This is a common hardening measure intended to defeat exactly this type of exploit.  You may be able to disable it for your program in order to do your test; on Linux you can link using `-z execstack`, or use the [`execstack` tool](https://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack).